# vba coloring duplicate and re-order list

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of zip codes, their corresponding counties and their quantities, sorted by quantities largest to smallest. However, I need to re-arrange the list in a way so duplicates are next to each other while quantities are not being affected. For the coloring part, I only want to add the font color, once, to the zip code that can be in two counties.

What I did was I added a help column, A and use countif function to find duplicate zip codes and add font color to all duplicates, so not quite the result I want. I think it has something to do with the finding the duplicates and inserting and copying which I am not familiar.

```
Sub test()        
    Dim Rng1, Rng2, cell As Range
    Dim LR1, LR2 As Long

    LR1 = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Set Rng1 = Range("B2", "B" & LR1)

    For i = 2 To LR1
        Cells(i, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng1, Cells(i, 2).Value)
    Next i

    Set Rng2 = Range("A2", "A" & LR1)

    For Each cell In Rng2
        If cell.Value > 1 Then
            cell.Offset(, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Else
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Please see picture for desire results. As you can see zip code 32413 can be either Walton or Bay County so I need to move the second entry right below the first. Also I only want to add font color to the second occurrence of the zip code that can be in two counties.

[image]

Comment: No need for VBA. 1) Sort columns B:D on Col B Ascending; Then Cold C Ascending. 2) Use conditional formatting on range B2:B12. Formula will be `(B2=B1)`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman that would make the quantities jumbled!

Comment: @bulbus - now I see what you mean by quantities not being affected.

Comment: I have tried different ways of sorting but have failed and that's why I turned to using writing VBA codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just built and tested this and it works:

```
Option Explicit

Sub StackedSortByZip()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws

        Dim rZip As Range
        Set rZip = .Range("B2:B12")

        Dim rCel As Range
        For Each rCel In rZip

            'look for another occurence of zip code
            Dim rFound As Range
            Set rFound = Range(rCel.Offset(1), rCel.End(xlDown)).Find(rCel, lookat:=xlWhole)

            'if it's found
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                rFound.Resize(1, 3).Cut ', cut the zip with lower quantity
                'insert under original zip (as long as it's not last line)
                If rFound.Address <> rCel.Offset(1).Address Then rCel.Offset(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            End If

        Next

        'set conditional formatting
        With rZip
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=B1=B2"
            With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
                .SetFirstPriority
                .Font.Color = 255
            End With
        End With


    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: @sc1324 - not so much super. I thought of the best way to do it manually, then wrote the code for that. :)